# mongo command not working on fedora

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I installed mongodb using dnf/yum and I then tried running the command

> mongo meteor --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())

,but I get the following error:

> MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8
>   connecting to: meteor
>   2017-03-17T14:09:56.787+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
>   2017-03-17T14:09:56.787+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>   connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
>   @(connect):1:6 
>   
> exception: connect failed

I searched for a solution but I couldn't find anything that worked for me. Please help me resolve the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first I am on fedora 24.

I found this thread https://www.learntutors.com/install-mongodb-fedora-24/

The only thing I changed to make things work is the install command to the following

> dnf install --allowerasing  mongodb-org mongodb-org-server

This was so the mongodb package that ships with fedora 24 could be erased in favor of mongodb-org mongodb-org-server. Hope this helps someone else. cheers.